# How can I define a torsion force field for $n$ points in space?

Tags: intermolecular-forces, molecular-dynamics

I would like to define a model for torsion force field between $n$ point in space.

I thought to generalize the [OPLS model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OPLS):

$$
\sum_\mathrm{dihedrals} \left( \frac {V_1} {2} \left [ 1 + \cos (\phi-\phi_1) \right ] 
                + \frac {V_2} {2} \left [ 1 - \cos (2\phi-\phi_2) \right ] 
                + \frac {V_3} {2} \left [ 1 + \cos (3\phi-\phi_3) \right ] 
                + \frac {V_4} {2} \left [ 1 - \cos (4\phi-\phi_4) \right ] \right)
$$

How can I make them to lie in the same plane allowing fluctuations of $\pm10^\mathbf{o}$?

Comment: It is just a Fourier series; it could have as few or as many terms as you want.

Comment: @IvanNeretin, so the idea is to construct the potential I want and then fit it to a Fourier series?

Comment: Looks like so.$\,$